# Missing partial users/user

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have a rails server which accepts json requests. I intend to use it as a server for my iphone app. I get this error:

```
Missing partial users/user with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/Users/chalamphongpandey/rails_projects/comboo/app/views" * "/Users/chalamphongpandey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@railstutorial/gems/devise-2.2.3/app/views"
```

I dont understand what partial is missing because I am not rendering any view. All the create action(which in routes I have configured to be as sign_up) does is accept information such as username, password, name etc, create a user and sends back a confirmation(json format)

The url i sent in is

```
http://localhost:3000/sign_up.json?username=chalami&password=chalami&name=chalami&email=3020@gmail.com
```

The url I sent in through my browser and not through the app. I wanted to test it through the browser first.
my code is

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
respond_to :json
def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])
if @user.save
    render :json => {:status => "200", :message => "Signed up successfully"}
else
    render :json => {:status => "400", :message => "Failed"}
end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly that error is saying that you are missing a partial `_user.html.erb` in your **app/view/users** Because if there is not partial then therefore your form cannot be rendered. As the error states at the start `Missing partial users/user with` and then as you continue to look through the error it then says it tried to search in `earched in: * "/Users/chalamphongpandey/rails_projects/comboo/app/views" * "`

If you have in one of your views the following

```
<%= render 'users/user' %>
```

it will look for a partial named `users/user in the app/views/#{controller_name}`

Missing `respond_to do |format|` block. Further reading - [Respond_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to)

Comment: Why do I need a view? All I want from the controller is to accept a json request and render a json response, hence the .json extension instead of .html or am I missing something?

Comment: okay tell me this where is your `respond_to do |format|` block?

Comment: Actually after adding the block it works, I always thought the `respond_to do |format|` was intended for multiple format rendering. Thankyou

Comment: I have this new problem though, I can't seem to sign_up a new user, could you help me with that? I'll post my user.rb model in the question

Comment: This would be complete different question as your initial question has been resolved

Comment: will post a new question. Thanks